# Image standardization from variable positioning

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

So basically I am designing an instrument that takes picture of a sample and based on its luminosity gives an output result by using the optical density calibration. I had initially hard coded my pixel coordinate values into my code but I had to change my camera and now all the coordinates have changed because of a different zoom and focus. What I need to do is to standardized all the images so that they dont depend on the camera positioning. One image can be kept as a template so that newer images can be compared against it and then resized and/or rotated in a way that the object of interest (rectangular) essentially occupies the same pixel coordinates.

I've implemented a part of it on ImageJ, where I detect edges of my object and then return its corner edge values. Cant seem to get the corner values in PIL python.

I've found an inefficient way of doing this but still it is far from being standardized. First I split into rgb channels. Convert it into B/W using thresholding (which is a problem because different pictures have different intensities and intensity distribution) 
Then for each I use the edge detection filter. So that edges are the only thing left in white. Read the pixel values of all the whites. Find the lowest white along the y-axis that gives me my first edge. Transcend across this edge and find the lowest x-value to find my first corner.

[Sample of Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL6EZ.png)

Comment: please add what you tried, in the question description

Comment: Hey thanks I have made some edits. Let me know if this is alright